# Linux mint 17.1 keeps crashing

Tags: linux-mint, memory

I have recently installed Linux Mint 17.1 Cinnamon on an Compaq presario c700 w/intel pentium dual core. It is dual booting with windows vista. The partition size is 19gb.

I haven't installed anything other than google chrome.

Whenever I open mozilla firefox, after a minute or so, the computer screen goes black, but something is still running. I had to do a hard reset. This was repeated 3-4 times.

I decided to install google chrome. This worked for 2-3 minutes but encountered the same problem.

Comment: Something similar is happening to me. But only with flash player in Chrome, not in Firefox.

Comment: Can you run memtest ala http://forums.linuxmint.com/viewtopic.php?f=90&t=93688 ?

Comment: Mint was my first distro and I had lots of trouble with it, but after going to Debian I've hardly had a problem since.

Answer (score 0):

So it's solved.

There were two things that I did.

First i updated the system and then installed mate desktop. Now it works like a charm.